# Parent iframe won't reload when popup closes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, onbeforeunload, window.onunload

I have a function in parent iframe.

```
var reloadFrameWindow = function() {
    "use strict";
    var doc, myFrame, keyElem, url;
    doc = document;
    myFrame = doc.getElementById("myFrame");
    keyElem = doc.getElementById("key"); 
    if (myFrame && keyElem) {
        keyElem.value = keyElem.value + "X";
        url = myFrame.src;
        url = updateQueryStringParameter(url, "key", keyElem.value);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function() {
                myFrame.src = newUrl;
            }
        });
    }
 };
```

In my pop up I have added

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    "use strict";
    window.opener.reloadFrameWindow();
};
```

1. If I close it on IE11, 8 the parent iframe gets reloaded.
2. If I close it on chrome, it doesn't reload parent iframe but the key
   element value does increase by 1 in both cases.

Note: I want this to fire only when it closes, not when the back button is clicked. But I wouldn't mind if it happens in both cases

Comment: `onbeforeunload` is very restrictive with regard to what is allowed and differs browser to browser. You can not control user clicking back button vs other ways window can be unloaded. It's all or none

Comment: Sure I would take all then none but that doesn't explain why key element value is change but parent window is never reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i found that doing this in chrome works..

```
jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: newUrl,
                success: function() {
                    myFrame.src = newUrl;
                }
            });
```